# PHP: The page isn’t redirecting properly, Too many redirects

Tags: php, postgresql, redirect

I tried implementing a system wherein the user enters his username and phone number, when the form is submitted, it checks the database to verify the number and username based on it's existence. An SMS is sent to that number. He gets a popup to enter the OTP code.

However on entering the OTP code I get an error of redirecting loops. I'll just explain the flow of the files below:

INDEX.PHP -> LOGIN.PHP -> OTP.PHP -> CHECK_OTP.PHP -> HOME.PHP

Those are the files being used. It reaches the otp page and when you enter, it does authenticate successfully but it goes into a loop. I will post the code to see what is wrong with the OTP authentication code.

```
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['verify'])) {
if (empty($_POST['otp'])) {
$error = "OTP is invalid";
}
else
{
// Post OTP
$otp=$_POST['otp'];
}
$otp = stripslashes($otp);
$otp = pg_escape_string($otp);
$check = "select * from otp where otp = '$otp'";
$ret_check = $dbConnection->executeQuery($check);
$ret_num = $dbConnection->numRows($ret_check);
$cust_code = '';
while($row = $dbConnection->fetchRow($ret_check)){
    $cust_code = $row[0];
}
$cust_code;
if($ret_num != 1){
    $error = "Wrong OTP entered";
    header("Location: otp-home.php");
}
else {
    echo $_SESSION['login_user'] = $cust_code;
    header("Location: home.php");
}
```

I hope this is enough. If anything else is required. Please let me know. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: This happen to when you try and redirect to a page that you have previously redirected to. Try and restructure your routing

Comment: Is there anyway to narrow it down to which page the redirection is causing a problem?

Comment: Try adding ob_start() as a hack just before your session_start() as a temporary hack.

Comment: Just tried it, still the same thing. Problem is there are 4 pages. Should I put all of them here?

Comment: The browser is stopping you from hammering the server with a bunch of requests. This is most likely due to the header() sending you to a page which in turn sends you to the same page (or page with the same header()). Look at you redirects and make sure your not redirecting to the same page

Comment: Ok. I'll try merging two pages, in order to avoid a previous `header()` and see if it helps.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set a session and check if that session is set on the next page and use that for the redirect

Comment: I tried merging 2pages. But it redirects back to the main login page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127978/discussion-between-mueyiwa-moses-ikomi-and-david-noronha).

Comment: I feel so stupid, There was a session file that was included in the homepage, which was redclaring a session. It took me an entire day to realize the issue was, I was just wasting my time on just one file where I thought the issue would be. Thank you so much for your help. God Bless

Comment: Glad it sorted. You're welcome